# How to display something from one page to another using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

This is my code so far:

The HTML:

```
<form>
    <label>First Name</label> <input type="text" class="first" /><br />
    <label>Last Name</label> <input type="text" class="last" /><br />
    <label>Age</label> <input type="text" class="age" /><br />
    <input type="button" class="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The PHP:

```
$first = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first']);
$last = mysql_real_escape_string($last = $_POST['last']);
$age = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['age']);

$query = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO people(first, last, age) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$age')" );

if ($query) {
    echo "Success: $first $last has been entered";
} else {
    echo "FAIL!!!";
}
```

The JQuery:

```
$('.submit').click(function() {

    var first = $('.first').val();
    var last = $('.last').val();
    var age = $('.age').val();

    var dataString = 'first=' + first + '&last=' + last + '&age=' + age;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'practise_process.php',
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
            alert('success');
        }, error: function() {
            alert('error');
        }
    });

});
```

Right now I can use the above code to enter form input into a database via the ajax function without refreshing the page. But how can I display something from the PHP script (practise_process.php) to the form page?

this part:

```
if ($query) {
    echo "Success: $first $last has been entered";
} else {
    echo "FAIL!!!";
}
```

### EDIT

I made this change to my PHP file:

```
if ($query) {
    $message = "Success: $first $last has been entered";
} else {
    $message = "FAIL!!!";
}


echo "

<script type='text/javascript'>
var foo = $message;
</script>

";
```

and changed the success of the ajax function on my form page to this:

```
    success: function() {
        alert(foo);
    }
```

But the var foo which was set on the PHP file isn't being recognized on the form file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
//other code here.....

if ($query) {
    $message = "Success: $first $last has been entered";
} else {
    $message = "FAIL!!!";
}

echo $message;
<?

//in jQuery function...


$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'practise_process.php',
        data: dataString,
        success: function(foo) {
            alert(foo);
        }, error: function() {
            alert(foo);
        }
    });
```

If you make 'foo' the function parameter, it will receive whatever is echo'd out from the PHP file.  You can then use JS to alert() it to the user or display it.  Additionally, if you use mysqli for your db connection you can echo out m`ysqli_error($dbLink);` to alert the SQL error if there is one.  The JS variable must be set on the client-side, but it can be fed by your PHP on the server-side.

Comment: OK so the only change I made now is adding foo within the function parenthesis like you show in the ajax - all my other code in the "edit" portion is the same. Now I actually get feedback from the PHP script. Only problem is, instead of getting just the message, I get this in the alert box: `<script type='text/javascript'>

var foo = Success: John Doe has been entered;

</script>

` How do I only get the message without the javascript tags and var foo equals to part.

Comment: did you remove this from your PHP file:

`<script type='text/javascript'>
var foo = $message;
</script>`

?

Looks like you're still trying to echo out the Js code from the PHP file rather than just `$message`

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to do something extra to prevent the page reload. This is done by returning `false` from your click event handler function.

```
$('.submit').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        ... blah blah blah ...
    });

    return false; // this stops page refresh by preventing further event processing
});
```

Next, make your success function take in a parameter for the response to see what came back from the server. Example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'practise_process.php',
    data: dataString,
    success: function(response) {
        alert('Received this from server: ' + response);
    }, error: function() {
        alert('error');
    }

});
```

See the jQuery docs on $.ajax for all the details on the success function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Hi, I tried defining a JavaScript variable in the php file and tried to call it in the alert of the success function on the form page and it didn't work. It looks like a variable defined on one page isn't recognized on another page. Please see my edit.

Comment: Hi Sammy, undo your edits  :)  I overlooked the fact that you might be getting a page refresh based on your current code. I updated my answer to add a `return false;` to try to prevent the refresh. Now try adding the response parameter to the success function and alerting it, it should show what you were trying to send back from your PHP script. Hope this helps.